# Mac OS shortkey for popping up the Finder window?

Tags: macos, finder, keystrokes

I would like to know whether there is a shortkey in Mac Os for my finder window to pop up?

For example, when I download a file via firefox, I want to go to the ~/Downloads directory. This process is tedious using mouse, so I am looking for a shortkey for me to have finder pop up, and then I can use shift-apple-G to go to the Downloads directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I love quick keys too. Personally I use finder windows accessed via command tab. I dragged my Downloads directory into the sidebar (it should be there already), or you can CMD drag the folder onto the toolbar at the top of the finder window. So: command-tab to finder, click Downloads in the sidebar or toolbar depending on where you put it, and viola! Alternatively, you could drag the downloads folder to the dock (it should be there already). Or, swipe 4 fingers down to reveal Finder windows (the "Mission Control" option in system preferences -> trackpad), then click desktop to select finder.

In Automator you could build a workflow and save it as a service. In Automator use open finder. Then select the service and assign a keyboard shortcut in system preferences -> keyboard -> keyboard shortcuts -> services. Good luck!